# are anonymous credentials a type of zero knowledge proof?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Are anonymous credentials (such as IBM Idemix) a type of zero knowledge proofs (ZKP)? if so what type of ZKP are they?

The papers such “Security without identification: transaction systems to make big brother obsolete” don not reference ZKP.

My understanding is they both refer to similar topics.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather call them a type of blind signatures. Since signatures stem from non interactive ZKP you can say that they are related.

Comment: Aren't blind signatures also a sub-category of ZKP since they provide the ability to sign data without viewing the data.

Comment: I don't think so since in ZKP the zero knowledge part concerns the key not the message. In Blind signatures the signer  does not see the message and also provides a ZKP of the key